# Jump, Julia : How to add constraints with different indexes a.c.a $x_i \leq z_j, \; \forall i, j$

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, julia, jump

I am having a constraint in the form :
$$ x_i \leq z_j, \quad \forall i, j \in \{1, 2, .., n\}$$
I know that if the right part of the equation was a constant so something like $x_i \leq c[i]$ I could write something like:
`@constraint(m, [i = 1:n], x[i] <= c[i])` 
But know that they have not always the same index , what can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
@constraint(m, [i=1:n, j=1:n], x[i] <= z[j])
```

or

```
for i in 1:n, j in 1:n
    @constraint(m, x[i] <= z[j])
end
```

You might want to read the documentation: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/constraints/#Containers-of-constraints

Or look at similar problems in the tutorials: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/linear/facility_location/#JuMP-implementation

You can also ask JuMP-specific questions on our forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13

Comment: Just a comment. I have found that, if the problem is big, your second approach performs better than the first, in terms of CPU and memory usage.

Comment: Sure. The first approach creates and returns a `Matrix{ConstraintRef}`, which can be useful if you want to access dual variables, etc. The second doesn't allocate or store the constraint references.